# Access low and high settings of an ETS Range attribute?

Tags: python, range, enthought

Here is an interactive Python session which uses components of the Enthought Tool Suite (ETS):

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:44:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]'
>>> import traits
>>> traits.__version__
'4.5.0'
>>> from traits.api import HasTraits, Range
>>> class Foo(HasTraits):
...     bar = Range (low=1, high=10)
...     
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.bar
1
>>> foo.bar._low
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_low'
```

I would like to be able to access the predefined limits on the `bar` attribute of a `Foo` instance.  How can this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to do this would be to use `low` and `high` traits and assign them as the limits of the `Range`

```
from traits.api import HasTraits, Range, Int


class Foo(HasTraits):
    high = Int(10)
    low = Int(1)
    bar = Range(high='high', low='low')
```

You can assign the traits dynamically:

```
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.bar = 5
>>> f.bar
5
>>> f.bar = 30
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/tim/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traits/trait_types.py", line 1785, in _set
self.error( object, name, value )
  File "/Users/tim/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traits/trait_handlers.py", line 172, in error value )
traits.trait_errors.TraitError: The 'bar' trait of a Foo instance must be 1 <= a number <= 10, but a value of 30 <type 'int'> was specified.
>>> f.high = 35
>>> f.bar = 30
>>> f.bar
30
```

Comment: OK, thanks for this clarification.  That is very helpful.  I've now accepted this as the preferred answer.

Answer (score 2):

`Range()` object has `_low` and `_high` attributes, which can be accessed. 
I suppose the underscore for them is used so that it does not shadow with `low` and `high` keyword parameters in `Range()`.

```
>>> import traits.api
>>> bar = traits.api.Range(low=1, high=10)
>>> bar._low
1
>>> bar._high
10
```

Accessing them as a class instance attribute is still possible, however you need to know the name of the variable (in this base `bar`), so that you can access it in `foo.traits()`, which is a dictionary of all traits:

```
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.traits()['bar'] # dictionary of all traits
<traits.traits.CTrait object at 0x000000000525A6D8>
>>> foo.traits()['bar'].trait_type
<traits.trait_types.Range object at 0x0000000005BA3EF0>
>>> foo.traits()['bar'].trait_type._low
1
>>> foo.traits()['bar'].trait_type._high
10
```

Comment: Sorry about the abbreviated comment; I'm a new poster and am having difficulty with the StackOverflow interface.  My original question has been edited to emphasize that `bar` is a `class` instance attribute.  Thanks for your interest!

Comment: @jimvickroy: please see my updated answer, it took me a while to figure. Please accept my answer if you found it helpful, in order to mark the question as answered. (and we both get reputation)

Comment: Wow!  That is ugly!  Not your answer ... but the procedure to do it :-)  Thanks for figuring this out!  I'm new to ETS Traits and find them very useful (except in situations like this).